# Fast (twice in <1s) pressing of the same key on keyboard is not recognized correctly. What can it be?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard

If I press any button 2 times quickly (I mean with less one second of delay between the keystrokes), Ubuntu doesn't detect the second one. In particularly, Ubuntu seems to detect the pressure because when I push the backspace, I can listen the sound related to the beating, but it has no effect (the letter is not inserted in the text or deleted in backspace case). How to fix it?

Note: I used Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with your keyboard. Did you check that with a different device or OS?

Comment: Yes I checked and my keyboard is OK:if I run another OS or merely I start a console without X activated (pressing CTRL+ALT+F1) it works properly. It's really strange issue.

Comment: You could try the following:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/kbdrate.8.html

There you can set the repeat spead that you have with your keyboard. Another way would be to set in bios if possible. But you said that it works in other os - so I would stick to my first link.

Comment: Hi @Peterling, thank you for your help. I tried to set rate= 10.9cps and delay= 250ms and also delay=100ms and rate=30' but the problem still exists. Have you got any other idea?

Comment: Can I reinstall all system files related to keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Its with the key board.

This is called filter keys. you have to uncheck this function, this function does not recognize multiple strikes of same key in continuance.

Press shift 5 times, you will either 1) get a window of sticky keys. press 'settings'and uncheck filter keys or, 2) see a small clock on the lower right hand side of your screen, click on that and it will open sticky keys window and rest follow the same as in 1). and you are done :)

Let me know if it helps !! :)

Comment: Thanks @mneeti, you're answer has been very useful. if I press shift 5 times, nothing appears but, I find the solution: It's not "sticky keys" enabled, but "Bounce Keys"! I'll post the screenshot that show how to fix the problem. Than you very much again.

Comment: @aldo85ita, if this answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer, this will give mneeti and you points

Answer (score 0):

As tested and verified on **Ubuntu 18.04**:

Check for the "Bounce Keys" if they are on. For repeated key presses (presses of the same key), **Bounce Keys should be off**.

**To switch it off:**
Activites **-->** Settings **-->** Universal Access(AccessX) **-->** Bounce Keys.
 Toggle to switch on or off. You might check out other settings as well.

Check out the documentation to know more or verify:-
[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-bouncekeys.html.en)

**For other versions, look out for similar function/feature name, if it is not the same.**

Answer (score -1):

To fix the problem, *dis*able ["Bounce Keys"](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/a11y-bouncekeys.html.en) in the [universal access menu](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/a11y-icon.html.en).

[image: screenshot showing Bounce Keys setting]